# Logging in with a BOT in a private WIKI to read feedrecentchanges action

Tags: mediawiki-api

I have a private wiki installation:

```
MediaWiki   1.34.0
PHP     7.2.27
```

with

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
```

in LocalSettings.php

What I'd like to do is to read recent changes through a bot, in order to display "*Recente Wiki news - check them out!*" to my users when they log into another web app.

So, following [this example on official documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login), first I created a BOT Password.

Then I try to call:

```
https://mywiki.myhosting.com/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&type=login&format=json
```

and get the answer

```
{"error":{"code":"readapidenied","info":"You need read permission to use this module.","*":"See https://mywiki.myhosting.com/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."}}
```

If I try the same querystring in a new tab after loggin in to the Wiki (that is - the browser has the authentication cookie already) then I get the answer:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"tokens":{"logintoken":"0a0_some_token_letters_518+\\"}}}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

In my understanding, if I don't get this first token, then I will not be able to make the second login call where I am supposed to use my BOT username / password, right?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug that has been fixed [just a few days ago](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T245149). As a workaround, you can just make a login request without a token. You'll get an error message, but there will be a token in it. That login workflow is deprecated and will be removed eventually, but right now it works.

Comment: Thank you TGR! That's perfect! Too bad I couldn't find this link myself.

Comment: Trying to use your suggestion, @Tgr, is still not working.
I first try to login without `lgtoken` parameter, and get the token as a parameter of `NeedToken` warning, as you said.
Then, when I use this token in the `lgtoken` parametere of the next request, I still get the same warning answer, with a new token.
Yet, I still can't login.
What is wrong now?

I think I'm going to try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers authentication.

Comment: Here's my 2nd json call:
`{
   "action": "login",
   "lgname": "my-user",
   "lgpassword": "my-password",
   "lgtoken": "a5b287ac22e9fe1953ba53087a8fa8015e7f8227+\\",
   "format": "json"
}
`

Comment: You need to preserve the session cookies set in the first request (unless you use OAuth).

Comment: There are quite a few [client libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code), that might be easier than writing your own bot. (Which still shouldn't be too hard, but login is one of the less intuitive parts.)

Comment: Thanks TGR I ended up using OAuth Consumers-only authentication https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers